# In what text(s) is the Naga gayatri mantra found?

Tags: mantras, identification-request, naga

Various sites on the internet list some variation on the naga gayatri mantra, such as the following:

> ōṁ navakulāye vidhmahe
>    viśadantāye dhīmahi
>    tanno sarpa pracodayāt

I've been unable to find where the mantra is derived from, however, or which version is the original. Can anyone point me to a text which includes the mantra?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just found that mantra in Patha Bheda of First Anuvaka of [Mahanarayana Upanishad](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/mahanarayana.html?lang=sa). Mahanarayana Upanishad contains some Gayatri Mantras and it looks like some variants/lections include this mantra as follows:

> गायत्र्याः ।
>
> तत्पुरुषाय विद्महे महादेवाय धीमहि । तन्नो रुद्रः प्रचोदयात् ॥ २३॥
> तत्पुरुषाय विद्महे वक्रतुण्डाय धीमहि । तन्नो दन्तिः प्रचोदयात् ॥ २४॥
> तत्पुरुषाय विद्महे चक्रतुण्डाय धीमहि । तन्नो नन्दिः प्रचोदयात् ॥ २५॥
> तत्पुरुषाय विद्महे महासेनाय धीमहि । तन्नः षण्मुखः प्रचोदयात् ॥ २६॥
> तत्पुरुषाय विद्महे सुवर्णपक्षाय धीमहि । तन्नो गरुडः प्रचोदयात् ॥ २७॥
> वेदात्मनाय विद्महे हिरण्यगर्भाय धीमहि । तन्नो ब्रह्म प्रचोदयात् ॥ २८॥
> नारायणाय विद्महे वासुदेवाय धीमहि । तन्नो विष्णुः प्रचोदयात् ॥ २९॥
> वज्रनखाय विद्महे तीक्ष्णदꣳष्ट्राय धीमहि । तन्नो नारसिꣳहः प्रचोदयात् ॥ ३०॥
> भास्कराय विद्महे महद्द्युतिकराय धीमहि । तन्नो आदित्य्यः प्रचोदयात् ॥ ३१॥
> वैश्वानरय विद्महे लालीलाय धीमहि । तन्नो अग्निः प्रचोदयात् ॥ ३२॥
> कात्यायनाय विद्महे कन्याकुमारि धीमहि । तन्नो दुर्गिः प्रचोदयात् ॥ ३३॥
>
> [पाठभेदः:
> चतुर्मुखाय विद्महे कमण्डलुधराय धीमहि । तन्नो ब्रह्मा प्रचोदयात् ॥
> आदित्याय विद्महे सहस्रकिरणाय धीमहि । तन्नो भानुः प्रचोदयात् ॥
> पावकाय विद्महे सप्तजिह्वाय धीमहि । तन्नो वैश्वानरः प्रचोदयात् ॥
> महाशूलिन्यै विद्महे महादुर्गायै धीमहि । तन्नो भगवती प्रचोदयात् ॥
> सुभगायै विद्महे कमलमालिन्यै धीमहि । तन्नो गौरी प्रचोदयात् ॥
> **नवकुलाय विद्महे विषदन्ताय धीमहि । तन्नः सर्पः प्रचोदयात् ॥**]

In IAST:

> gāyatryāḥ ।
>
> tatpuruṣāya vidmahe mahādevāya dhīmahi । tanno rudraḥ pracodayāt ॥ 23॥
>   tatpuruṣāya vidmahe vakratuṇḍāya dhīmahi । tanno dantiḥ pracodayāt ॥ 24॥
>   tatpuruṣāya vidmahe cakratuṇḍāya dhīmahi । tanno nandiḥ pracodayāt ॥ 25॥
>   tatpuruṣāya vidmahe mahāsenāya dhīmahi । tannaḥ ṣaṇmukhaḥ pracodayāt ॥ 26॥
>   tatpuruṣāya vidmahe suvarṇapakṣāya dhīmahi । tanno garuḍaḥ pracodayāt ॥ 27॥
>   vedātmanāya vidmahe hiraṇyagarbhāya dhīmahi । tanno brahma pracodayāt ॥ 28॥
>   nārāyaṇāya vidmahe vāsudevāya dhīmahi । tanno viṣṇuḥ pracodayāt ॥ 29॥
>   vajranakhāya vidmahe tīkṣṇadaꣳṣṭrāya dhīmahi । tanno nārasiꣳhaḥ pracodayāt ॥   30॥
>   bhāskarāya vidmahe mahaddyutikarāya dhīmahi । tanno ādityyaḥ pracodayāt ॥ 31॥
>   vaiśvānaraya vidmahe lālīlāya dhīmahi । tanno agniḥ pracodayāt ॥ 32॥
>   kātyāyanāya vidmahe kanyākumāri dhīmahi । tanno durgiḥ pracodayāt ॥ 33॥
>
> [pāṭhabhedaḥ:
>   caturmukhāya vidmahe kamaṇḍaludharāya dhīmahi । tanno brahmā pracodayāt ॥
>   ādityāya vidmahe sahasrakiraṇāya dhīmahi । tanno bhānuḥ pracodayāt ॥
>   pāvakāya vidmahe saptajihvāya dhīmahi । tanno vaiśvānaraḥ pracodayāt ॥
>   mahāśūlinyai vidmahe mahādurgāyai dhīmahi । tanno bhagavatī pracodayāt ॥
>   subhagāyai vidmahe kamalamālinyai dhīmahi । tanno gaurī pracodayāt ॥
>   **navakulāya vidmahe viṣadantāya dhīmahi । tannaḥ sarpaḥ pracodayāt ॥]**

You can get ITRANS from [mahanarayana.itx](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/mahanarayana.itx).

Note that Mahanarayana Upanishad is different from Tripad-Vibhuti-MahanArayana Upanishad or Yajniki Upanishad.

Comment: You should probably [transliterate](http://www.learnsanskrit.org/tools/sanscript) to IAST.

Comment: @sv. ITRANS can be got(ten) from [itx file](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/mahanarayana.itx)

Comment: Linga Purana also has Gayatri mantras for various Deities. But i could not find the Sarpa Gayatri there.