# Where can I find the Gayatri mantra commonly used?

Tags: gayatri-mantra

Where can I find the Gayatri mantras for deities commonly worshipped like Lord Shiva, Vishnu, Brahma etc?

I found some video from YouTube but not sure if its safe to chant.

Comment: The domain of the question should be a finite set. You can declare some bounds.

Comment: Mahanarahana Upanishad contains some Gayatri Mantras, I discussed [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22956/277).

Answer (score 12):

One can find Gayatri Mantras for many Deities in the minor Upanishad called Mahanarayana.

Or else one find some of them from [Linga Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/lingapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=26) too:

> The various Swarupas of Gayatri as created by Maha Deva and the
>   related Mantras are:
>
> Tatpurushaaya vidmahey Vaagshuddhaaya Dhimahi tannah **Shivah**
>   Prachodayaat
>
> Ganaambikaayai vidmahey Karma saadhyaih cha dhimahi, Tanno **Gauri**
>   Prachodayaat/
>
> Tatpurushaaya vidmahey Maha Devaaya Dhimahi, Tanno **Rudrah**
>   prachodayaat/
>
> Tatpurushaaya vidmahey Vakratundaaya Dhimahi, Tanno **Dantih**
>   prachodayaat/ (this is for Lord Ganesha)
>
> Maha Senaaya vidmahey Vaagvishuddhaaya dhimahi,Tannah **Skandah**
>   prachodayaat/
>
> Tikshna shringaaya vidmahey Veda paadaaya dhimahi, Tanno **Vrishah**
>   prachodayaat/
>
> Harivaktraaya vidmahey Rudravaktraaya dhimahi, Tanno **Nandee**
>   prachodayaat/
>
> Naraayanaaya vidmahey Vaasudevaaya dhimahi,Tanno **Vishnuh**
>   prachodayaat/
>
> Mahaambikaayai vidmahey karma siddhaaih dhimahi, Tanno **Lakshmi**
>   prachodayaat/
>
> Samruddhaayai vidmahey Vishnunaikena dhimahi, Tanno **Dharaa**
>   prachodayaat/
>
> Vainateyaaya vidmahey Suvarna pakshaaya dhimahi, Tanno **Garudah**
>   prachodayaat/
>
> Padmodbhavaaya vidmahey Veda Vaktraaya dhimahi, Tannah **Srashta**
>   prachodayaat/
>
> Shivaasya jaayai vidmahey Deva rupaayai dhimahi, Tanno **Vaachaa**
>   prachodayaat/
>
> Devaraajaaya vidmahey vajrahastaaya dhimahi, Tannah **Shakrahy**
>   prachodayaat/ (this is for Indra)
>
> Rudra netraaya vidmahey Shaktihastaaya dhimahi, Tanno **Vahnih**
>   prachodayaat/
>
> Vaivaswataaya vidmahey Dandahastaaya dhimahi, Tanno **Yamah**
>   prachodayaat/
>
> Nishaacharaaya vidmahey Khadga hastaaya dhimahi, Tanno **Nirrutih**
>   prachodayaat/
>
> Shuddhahastaaya vidmahey Paasha hastaaya dhimahi, Tanno **Varunah**
>   prachodayaat/
>
> Sarva Praanaaya vidmaheyYashti hastaaya dhimahi,Tanno **Vaayuh**
>   prachodayaat/
>
> Yaksheswaraaya vidmahey Gadaa hastaaya dhimahi, Tanno **Yakshah**
>   prachodayaat/
>
> Sarveshwaraaya vidmahey Shula hastaaya dhimahi,Tanno **Rudrah**
>   prachodayaat/
>
> Katyaayanaaya vidmahey Kanya kumaaryai dhimahi,Tanno **Durgaa**
>   prachodayaat/

The Gayatri Mantras for various Deities are also found on [Hindupedia.com](http://www.hindupedia.com/eng/index.php?title=G%C4%81yatri_Mantras_of_Several_Gods&redirect=no) :

But none of the sites contain the respective Mantra for Lord Bhairava.

You can find his Mantras from [this page](https://www.dhevee.org/bhairava-gayatri-mantra/).

> Om Kalakalaya Vidmahe Kalathithaya Dhimahi Thanno Kala Bhairva
>   Prachodayath.
>
> OR
>
> Om Soola Hastaya Vidmahe Shvana Varaya dhimahi Thanno Bhairava
>   Prachodayath

As regards, whether it is safe to chant them by looking them up from books or random sites-- then it is not. Unless you know how to pronounce correctly, you are wearing the sacred thread or you're having a Guru Diksha.

EDIT:

Gayatri Mantras for Lord Krishna:

> Om Damodaraya Vidmahe Rukmini Vallabhaya Dhimahi Tanno Krishna
>   Prachodayath.
>
> Or
>
> Om Devaki Nandanaya Vidmahe Vasudevaya Dhimahi Tanno Krishna
>   Prachodayath.

For Gopala it is:

> Om Gopalaya Vidmahe Gopijana Vallabhaya Dhimahi Tanno Gopalah
>   Prachodayath.

For Radha it is:

> Om Vrishabhanujayai Vidmahe Krishna Priyei Dhimahi Tanno Radha
>   Prachodayath.

For Sri Rama:

> Om Dasharathaya Vidmahe Sita Vallabhaya Dhimahi Tanno Ramah
>   Prachodayath.

Comment: Is there any for Lord Krishna?

Comment: Yes there are.. do u want me to give in the answer or to u in chat room? @KrishnaShweta

Comment: Please add it here.

Comment: @Rickross i think gayatri mantra can be chaned for all although this age almost if we will keep this theory then men who are attracted towards relegion shall not able to do anything and AWGP(ALL WORLD GAYATRI PARAIVAR) allows mantra chanting for everybody.

I think one can listen them online and then pronounce what you say?

Comment: @KrishnaShweta Om Damodaraya Vidhmahe, Rukmini Vallabhaya Dhimahi, Thanno Krishna Prachodayath. (I think).

Comment: Interesting, the Ganesh Sukta mentions it as "Ekadantaya vidhmahe ...".

Comment: There can be more than one such Mantra for a particular Deity.. @BhargavRao..

Comment: @Fiercelord You can do it but scriptures don't approve the act.. so, that's why put those lines...

Comment: Yep, @Rickross, I'm aware of that. (For e.g: Ganesha also has Lambhodaraya vidmahe Mahodaraya deemahi ...), But I found it a bit interesting that in Linga Purana, only the starting is different. I remember reading a nice report of all the different gayatri mantras, but I'm not able to find it now.

Comment: It should be **Tannah** kaalabhairavah and **Tannah** Krishnah . @KrishnaShweta you also note this, in case you are reciting. Often people always tend to pronounce "Tannah" as "Tanno" without seeing the next syllables. Rickross Kindly edit it so that people may not be mislead. :)

Answer (score 6):

Mahanarayana Upanishad

> purushasya vidmahe sahasrakshasya mahadevasya dhimahi | tannorudrah
>   pracodayat || 22||
> tatpurushaya vidmahe mahadevaya dhimahi | tanno
>   rudrah pracodayat || 23||
> tatpurushaya vidmahe vakratundaya dhimahi
>   | tanno dantih pracodayat || 24||
> tatpurushaya vidmahe cakratundaya
>   dhimahi | tanno nandih pracodayat || 25||
> tatpurushaya vidmahe
>   mahasenaya dhimahi | tannah shanmukhah pracodayat ||
>   26||
> tatpurushaya vidmahe suvarnapakshaya dhimahi | tanno garudah
>   pracodayat || 27||
> vedatmanaya vidmahe hiranyagarbhaya dhimahi |
>   tanno brahma pracodayat || 28||
> narayanaya vidmahe vasudevaya
>   dhimahi | tanno vishnuh pracodayat || 29||
> vajranakhaya vidmahe
>   tikshnadam shtraya dhimahi | tannonarasim hah pracodayat || 30||
>   bhaskaraya vidmahe mahaddyutikaraya dhimahi | tanno adityyah
>   pracodayat || 31||
> vaishvanaraya vidmahe lalilaya dhimahi | tanno
>   agnih pracodayat || 32||
> katyayanaya vidmahe kanyakumari dhimahi |
>   tanno durgih pracodayat || 33||
> pathabhedahcaturmukhaya vidmahe
>   kamandaludharaya dhimahi | tanno brahma pracodayat ||
> adityaya
>   vidmahe sahasrakiranaya dhimahi | tanno bhanuh pracodayat
>   ||
> pavakaya vidmahe saptajihvaya dhimahi | tanno vaishvanarah
>   pracodayat ||
> mahashulinyai vidmahe mahadurgayai dhimahi | tanno
>   bhagavati pracodayat ||
> subhagayai vidmahe kamalamalinyai dhimahi |
>   tanno gauri pracodayat ||
> navakulaya vidmahe vishadantaya dhimahi |
>   tannah sarpah pracodayat ||

The answer given by Rickross is from the Linga Purana, but this is Mahanarayana Upanishad, so it has a few differences in mantras, though they may look the same apparently.

Comment: You can make grammatical corrections but u can not remove content from OP's post..that's not allowed.. So, if the original post contained Bhairava there's no way one can remove it..Also, if the original post do not have Brahma etc then u can not add it either..

Comment: Okay. got your point