# Gayatri mantras of Sri Vishnu's weapons

Tags: vishnu, mantras, weapon, puja

The commonly known weapons of Sri Vishnu are five in number - Panchajanya, Sudarshana, Sharanga, Nandaki and Koumodaki. Among the above 5, the Gayatri mantra of the first 2 are used in Pooja vidhana. I am aware of them.

I am interested in knowing the other three. Do any of you have information on this?

Also, for all the 5 (and in general any of the Gayatri mantras of deities), does any one have information of the rishi chanda and devata nyasa that
s to be done? Chanda is of course Gayatri chanda and the deity is something we can figure out but the rishis seem to be unknown.

Note - I have already checked [this one](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24109/where-can-i-find-the-gayatri-mantra-commonly-used). It's not covered